# Access SOAP Web service with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, sql-server, xcode

My web service is made to access data in a table from a SQL Server. The web service has a method that returns the first 25 rows of data as a DataSet. Can I use this DataSet class or do I need the method to return XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return a DataSet as Cocoa will not recognize it as an object considering it to be either an NSData binary or trash value. You need a method that returns an XML and a custom XML parser if you're using some sort of legacy API.

The best solution is to use JSON data format to return the concrete values. After the request has been made and values have been returned, you can parse them into a convenient NSArray or NSDictionary depending on the data format via SBJSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a DataSet object, no. Have you looked at [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/)? This might help you if you want to use XML. I recommend JSON, though, since .NET provides support for JSON (de)serialization and Cocoa provides the same. Convert the DataSet to JSON in your C#/VB and convert it back in your Objective-C; I think that is your most painless option.

Answer (score 0):

And remember when getting values from JSON they all have to fit this criteria initially.

- The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
- All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
  NSDictionary, or NSNull.
- All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
- Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

Read here for further insight. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html